# ¿Cuál sería la función a la que se llama así: example()[0](1)[1]?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de aprendizaje de JavaScript y tengo que escribir una función que devuelve 10 y se invoca de esta manera:

```
 example()[0](1)[1];
```

Por el momento, solo he llegado hasta el [0]:

```
function example() {
  return [
          first(),
         ];
}

function first() {
  return 10;
}

example()[0];
```

Comment: Hola Eulalia, bienvenida a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. No está muy claro lo que expones de  `example()[0](1)[1]` ya que lo que devuelve `first` se mete en un array quedando `[10]` y tras acceder al elemento 0, haces `(1)[1]` lo cual no se puede porque `10` no es una función. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info en como mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solución basada en tu código

Usando dos funciones debes devolver una referencia a la segunda función y no el resultado de su llamada.

```js
function example() {
  return [
          first,
         ];
}

function first() {
  return [ 0, 10 ];
}

console.log(example()[0](1)[1]);
console.log([ first ][0](1)[1]);
console.log(first(1)[1]);
console.log([ 0, 10 ][1]);
```

La llamada a `example()` devuelve un array con un único elemento `[0]` que es una función (*y no el resultado de llamar a una función*), `first`, que será llamada con el parámetro `(1)` en el siguiente paso.

La llamada efectiva será `first(1)` (como pongo en el segundo y tercer `console.log` y da igual lo que tenga de parámetro, la salida será la misma).

La llamada devolverá una matriz cuyo elemento `[1]` es 10 (como solicita tu ejercicio) y que es equivalente al último `console.log`.

## Solución en una única función

No es necesario crear una función adicional, se puede hacer todo en una única función:

```js
function example() {
  return [
    function() {
      return [ 0, 10 ];
    }
  ];
}

console.log(example()[0](1)[1]);
console.log([ function() { return [ 0, 10 ]; } ][0](1)[1]);
console.log([ 0, 10 ][1]);
```

Comment: Creo que hubiese sido mejor redactar la explicación y dejar al OP realizar el ejercicio... dejando que actualice la pregunta con nuevas dudas

Comment: @Eulalia Aunque no es necesario, estaría genial que aceptases alguna respuesta (con el check que está debajo de los botones de voto) para que la pregunta quedase marcada como respondida.

Answer (score 1):

Leyendo de derecha a izquierda la llamada:

```
example()[0](1)[1];
```

1. Tienes que obtener el 10 de la posición 1 de un array...
2. ... que es devuelto por una función que recibe como parámetro 1 ...
3. ... que está en la primera posición de un array ...
4. ... que es devuelto por la llamada a la función example sin parámetros.

Tienes que ir cumpliendo cada uno de los requisitos en ese orden.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible, metiendo una función anónima dentro de otra.

Esto es el segundo elemento de llamar a la función que está en el primer elemento de otro array, que fue generado llamando a una función.

```js
var array = [,[,10]]
array[0] = ()=>array[1]
var example = ()=>array
console.log(example()[0](1)[1])
```